# Custom select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vue.js

Подскажите как кастомизировать select>option ? 
Понимаю что напрямую это не сделать, направьте тогда проверенный плагин для этого

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=select

Answer (score 0):

Решений куча, вот отличный [плагин](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)
Можно думаю и специально для вью погуглить и npm пакетом найти. Но селектайза хватит за глаза.